# How to solve an exponential inequality with x in the term and the exponent

Tags: calculus, inequality

Given the following inequality:

$0.9x^2 - 10x^{-2}-2^{-x}ln(2) > 0$

How would one go about solving for x?

I tried

$ln(0.9x^2 - 10x^{-2}) > ln(2^{-x}ln(2)) \Leftrightarrow$
$ln(0.9x^2 - 10x^{-2}) > -x ln(2) + ln(ln(2))$

But I cannot get the $x^2$ out of the logarithm. 
Would you propose substitution? Which method would you recommend?

I'm not particularly skilled in calculus, thus am asking for help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think in our case the best method is: use WA: $x>1.855...$ or $-4.986...<x<-2.466...$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have examined (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.9x%5E2-10x%5E(-2)-2%5E(-x)*ln(2)%3E0), but how would one solve it per hand? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You won't be able to solve it algebraically, only numerically.

Comment: @GerryMyerson By numerically you mean using a calculator?

Comment: I mean by using an algorithm that gives increasingly better decimal approximations to the answer. By hand, by calculator, by computer, whatever.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand, thank you for your input! I'll try to search for a method. How would you solve it numerically by hand?

Comment: Do you know any numerical methods for solving equations, Revangelis? Anything you can do with a calculator, you can do by hand (only much slower).

Comment: @GerryMyerson to be honest, I don't. I am reading through https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Equation_Solving. I have now enough direction for my learning and don't want to take any more of your time. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you plot the function, you should notice that the roots are around $-5$, $-2$ and $+2$. This is sufficient to use Newton method using these guesses which will be updated according to 
$$x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$$ where
$$f(x)=\frac{9 x^2}{10}-\frac{10}{x^2}-2^{-x} \log (2)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{9 x}{5}+\frac{20}{x^3}+2^{-x} \log ^2(2)$$

This would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -5.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & -4.9870126600557926700 \\
 2 & -4.9868892963566025295 \\
 3 & -4.9868892853028242367 \\
 4 & -4.9868892853028241480
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & -2.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & -2.4003143813840846824 \\
 2 & -2.4651828012354987741 \\
 3 & -2.4663491782569381401 \\
 4 & -2.4663495411420586680 \\
 5 & -2.4663495411420937718 
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.0000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 1.8510134515088439146 \\
 2 & 1.8551163270689127836 \\
 3 & 1.8551206449314599113 \\
 4 & 1.8551206449361995291
\end{array}
\right)$$ which are the solutions for $20$ significant figures.